# Progress bar showing Image, dot at some regular intervals

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I need the progress bar which shows both the dot followed by icon after some regular intervals.
I am working on the camera module,when the snap is taken i need to show dot in the progress bar,which show the snap is taken.
   Then this snap is passed to the algorthim and it retuns boolen value,then i need to show icon.

if the duration is 1 minutes and the interval is 30 sec ,then in the progress bar control i need to show two dot and two icon in the progress bar.

Please provide me some solutions,below is the XAMl

XAML For the Progress bar

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle" TargetType="ProgressBar">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#BBC6C4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Padding="1">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Track" >
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF1D5666" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF09B6FF"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>

                            <Ellipse x:Name="progressdot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,7,0,0" Stroke="#FFA8A49B" Width="8" Height="8" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                            <Image x:Name="imgAcetowhiteness" Margin="89,7,0,0" Source="..\acetowhiteness.png" 
                                   Stretch="Fill" Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="progressdot1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,7,0,0" Stroke="#FFA8A49B" Width="8" Height="8" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
                            <Image x:Name="imgAcetowhiteness1" Margin="195,7,0,0" Source="..\acetowhiteness.png" 
                                   Stretch="Fill" Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

</Window.Resources> 

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBarone" Margin="48,10,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle}"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBartwo" Margin="48,20,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle}"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="PBarthree" Margin="48,30,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better? This is just a style and three progress bars.

Comment: if the progress bar is progressing i want to show icon and dot after 30 sec,then after 30 sec again i wnat to show icon and dot in the same progress bar.